# Algorithm kept secret, while output not

Tags: web-application

How would I implement an algorithm on a website that returned an answer to a user's input while keeping the algorithm itself secret?

For instance, the user would input a few values in a form, press submit, and an algorithm would be carried out on these data, to produce an output that is returned to the user through the webpage. However, the algorithm needs to remain secret, so, for example, it does not seem like it would be appropriate to use JavaScript as anyone could just Inspect Element, and get the algorithm.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: @mad_manny I have added some more detail to the question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to information security. You are basically asking how to design a website that supports forms and outputs a result.

Comment: Do you mean like any server side web language ever? (for example PHP?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the algorithm to be kept secret, it must run on the server only. If you let the client do the work (e.g. with JavaScript) you will have to send the client the code, and than it will be exposed to anyone snooping around. There is no way around that.

So just run the algorithm on the server - using Node.js, ASP.NET, PHP or whatnot. Off course, if the algorithm is simple a clever user may still be able to reverse engineer it, but thats a different matter.